# I want to add border bottom Dashed only in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhfGD.png)

border bottom style Dashed in react Native on

Answer (score 0):

Add this Style to the element.

```
borderBottom: ‘1px dashed grey’;
```

Comment: @codelearner my bad borderBottom: ‘1px dashed grey’ have edited the code.

Comment: There is no such use in react native.

Answer (score -1):

Setting border style on  to dashed or dotted for a single side does not render correctly on both iOS and Android

The is a known issue, so far no solution- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24224

If you want to apply a dashed border for all four sides below is the style for the same

```
borderStyle: "dashed",
borderRadius: 1,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: "red",
```

Comment: i want to add dashed border on bottom side only